# Remove rss widget title link

Tags: widgets, rss

I'm looking to remove the link and icon from rss feed widget. Is there a way it can be done? Obviously I don't want to modify the core files.

So desired output is:

```
<h3 class="widget-title">RSS Title</h3>
```

Instead of the default:

```
<h3 class="widget-title">
<a href="http://www.example.com/url/feed/" class="rsswidget">
    <img height="14" width="14" alt="RSS" src="http://example.com/wp-includes/images/rss.png" style="border:0" class="rss-widget-icon"></a> <a href="http://www.example.com/" class="rsswidget">RSS Title</a>
```

I know that there is widget_title filter, but I can't get it to work.

Code examples would be appreciated.

**More Details**

So there is this code in /wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-rss.php

```
/** This filter is documented in wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );

        $url = strip_tags( $url );
        $icon = includes_url( 'images/rss.png' );
        if ( $title )
            $title = '<a class="rsswidget" href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '"><img class="rss-widget-icon" style="border:0" width="14" height="14" src="' . esc_url( $icon ) . '" alt="RSS" /></a> <a class="rsswidget" href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '">'. esc_html( $title ) . '</a>';

        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( $title ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        }
        wp_widget_rss_output( $rss, $instance );
        echo $args['after_widget'];

        if ( ! is_wp_error($rss) )
            $rss->__destruct();
        unset($rss);
```

And I see that there is a filter there, but I'm not sure how to use it to remove the link and the icon.

Comment: can we see your code with the filter approach? so far you got no code at all.

Comment: don't really have code to show. Just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to modify a built-in widget. Unfortunately for you there is no easy solution to get the results you desire. As you figured out already, there is no filter hook to modify the whole title output.

### How to get the results?

1. Create your own Widget extending `WP_Widget_RSS` where you overwrite the parents method `widget` with your designated method. Then replace the build-in version with yours.

   Some help to get you started:

   ```
   class WP_Widget_RSS_Custom extend WP_Widget_RSS {
       public function widget($args, $instance) {
           // Copy parent function and modify to your needs…
       }
   }

   add_action('widgets_init', 'widget_WP_Widget_RSS_Custom_init');

   function widget_WP_Widget_RSS_Custom_init() {
       unregister_widget('WP_Widget_RSS');
       register_widget('WP_Widget_RSS_Custom');
   }
   ```
2. Create a JS based solution, that modifies the widget after DOM is ready.